# Inflection point of $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: calculus

The second derivative of the above function is negative throughout which indicates that the function is concave throughout. At $x=0$, the derivative is not defined. Can it be a point of inflection?

Comment: Could you cite the book where you see the concept "inflection". A satisfactory answer may very much depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

Even the first derivative of this function is not defined, i.e. $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not even diffrentaible at $0$ so no we dont say that $0$ is an inflection point.

Also note that at a point of inflection the function **must** change its concavity, but as you said this function is always concave, so it doesn't have an inflection point.

Comment: An *inflection point* is a point on a continuous curve where the concavity changes from concave down (concave) to concave upward (convex) or vice versa.  Your first paragraph is not necessary.

Comment: Yes you're right, I just wanted to point out that if the function is not differentiable at a certain point then this point can't be an inflection point.

Comment: Isn't x=0 an inflection point for $x^{1/3}$? The derivative is not defined there but curvature is changing.

Comment: $x^{1/3}$ is a continuous function.

Comment: My bad, you're right it is continuous, but it is also not an inflection point, you don't have the fact that $f''(0)=0$

Comment: If a function has a second derivative at an inflection point, then the second derivative must equal zero.  However, an inflection point can exist at a point where the second derivative is not defined.  The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ does have an inflection point at $x = 0$ even though it is not differentiable at $x = 0$ since the curve is continuous and its concavity changes from concave down (concave) to concave up (convex) there.

Comment: I checked many sites and all of them say that $f''(x)=0$ is a must to have an inflection point, even wolfram states this, I don't think it is enough for the function to be continuous, I think (also seen) that the second derivative must exist at the point of inflection and ofcourse must be equal to $0$.

Comment: If the function is differentiable then the second derivative must vanish. If the derivative doesn't exist then it can still be an inflection if the curvature changes around it.

Comment: I understand your point and it makes sense, but I still think that it is not right to call such a point an inflectiom point.